# Issues with adding markers with Google Maps Javascript API using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

So, I am trying to add a marker on the Google Maps which is part of the functionality of the react.js app I am developing.

```
const MapCode = document.createElement('script')
    MapCode.src =`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`
    window.document.body.appendChild(MapCode)

    MapCode.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
        this.initMap()
        this.targetedCityMarker()
    })
}

initMap(){
    new window.google.maps.Map(this.googleMap.current,{
        zoom: 7.5,
        center:{ lat: this.state.cityCoordinates[1], lng:this.state.cityCoordinates[0] },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    })
}

targetedCityMarker(){
    console.log('testing')
    new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: this.state.cityCoordinates[1], lng:this.state.cityCoordinates[0] },
        map:this.initMap(),
    })
}
```

The issue is, when I run the code, `initMap()`works . I can see the map on my page with map centre located at the defined coordinate. For the `targetedCityMarker`, `console.log('testing')`can be seen, but somehow the Marker part is not showing up. What has gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Marker()` initialization, you are trying to use `this.initMap()` as a map instance, however, that function does not return anything.

Try to return the map instance you initialized from that function:

```
initMap(){
    return new window.google.maps.Map(this.googleMap.current,{
        zoom: 7.5,
        center:{ lat: this.state.cityCoordinates[1], lng:this.state.cityCoordinates[0] },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    })
}
```

and then you'll be able to use it in your `Marker()` in a way you are doing it now.

Comment: YOUUUUUU ARE THE ONEEE! HOLY COWWW..IT WORRRKED...[after i calmed down] i will check-mark you answer later. i did click it but it says I have to wait a bit.

Comment: Heyy, can I ask you another a Google Maps related issue?

Comment: @LearnerSamuelX Sure, but create a new question if you think it’s a good StavkOverflow material... Otherwise we can probably do it on some chat or something...

Comment: I did create one, but no one seems can answer it, and that is why I am looking to you for help

Comment: Ah, right! I’m traveling around at the moment, but will find it and take a look at it later! ;)

Comment: I can send you a link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766899/issues-with-google-maps-javascript-api-marker-and-polylines-not-showing-togethe