# Issues with Google Maps Javascript API, Marker and Polylines NOT SHOWING together on a React.js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, oop

I am pretty sure the states and setState stuff are correct, so here is my code. What I did here was I assigned the map key with the function `this.initMap()`. To have a detailed look:

```
class Radar extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        //initialize methods here
        this.googleMap = React.createRef()

        //define states here
        this.state = {
            cityname:this.props.datasource.name,
            cityCoordinates:[this.props.datasource.coord.lon, this.props.datasource.coord.lat],
            winddirection:this.props.datasource.wind.deg,
            cityPool:[],
            borderLine:[]
        }
}


initMap(){
    return new window.google.maps.Map(this.googleMap.current,{
        zoom: 7.5,
        center:{ lat: this.state.cityCoordinates[1], lng:this.state.cityCoordinates[0] },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    })
}

targetedCityMarker(){
    new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: this.state.cityCoordinates[1], lng:this.state.cityCoordinates[0] },
        map:this.initMap()
    })
}

cityPoolPolyLine(){
    let citypool_coordinates=[]
    this.state.cityPool.map((i)=>{
        citypool_coordinates.push(i.location)
        return citypool_coordinates
    })

    console.log(this.state.borderLine)   
    console.log(citypool_coordinates)    
    new window.google.maps.Polyline({
        path: this.state.borderLine,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: "#2AA181",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        map:this.initMap()
      });
}

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/weather/radar').then((res)=>{
        console.log(res.data)
        this.setState({
            cityPool:res.data
        })
    })

    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/weather/radar_2').then((res)=>{
        this.setState({
            borderLine:res.data
        })
    })

    const MapCode = document.createElement('script')
    MapCode.src =`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&libraries=&v=weekly`
    window.document.body.appendChild(MapCode)
    

    MapCode.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
        this.initMap()
        this.targetedCityMarker()
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.cityPoolPolyLine()
        },4000)
    })
}
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='radar-page'>
                <h1>Weather Radar</h1>
                <p>City Name: {this.state.cityname}</p>
                <p>City Coordinates:Lon: {this.state.cityCoordinates[0]}, Lat: {this.state.cityCoordinates[1]}</p>
                <p>Wind Direction: {this.state.winddirection}˚ </p>
                <p>Selected Cities: * Write a query, setup the range, greater or less than the chosen city's coordinates *</p>
                <div id="google-map" ref={this.googleMap} style={{ width: '500px', height: '400px' }} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Radar
```

Is my use of `this.initMap()` correct? My instinct tells me this line or some of my confusion in regard with OOP is causing some troubles. So once I run, it shows the marker first with no polyline, and then the marker disappears but the poly line shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you instantiate your map multiple times. Every time you call `this.initMap()` you create a new map instance, so what you should do is call this method only once (probably in constructor), assign it to some variable and then use that variable when referring to your map in `Marker()` and `Polyline()` methods.

Comment: see? I knew you would be able to help me and you did!

Comment: but just a follow up question, so my issue here is I instantiated my map multiple times. And the Marker function was using the OLD map instance and the poly line is using the most recent instance, and that s why the marker is not showing? Is that right?